# Removing the last IP Address Octet in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, sockets, network-programming

In Ruby, I'm wanting to take my local IP address and convert it into my network id (e.g. 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.0)

```
require "socket"
local_ip = UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect("64.233.187.99", 1); s.addr.last}
```

This will give me my local ip, but how can I remove the last octet up to the dot(.)?

Comment: Changing the last octet will only work for 255.255.255.0 subnets.

Answer (score 5):

quick and dirty way would be something like

```
"192.168.1.1".rpartition(".")[0]
=> "192.168.1"
```

but if you know subnet mask or if you are running on subnets other than 24 bits (255.255.255.0), you should use `IPAddr` module, since network of those can be differ based on subnets.

```
> require 'IPAddr'
=> true
>  
> IPAddr.new("64.233.187.99/24").to_s
=> "64.233.187.0"

> IPAddr.new("64.233.187.99/20").to_s
=> "64.233.176.0"
```

refs:

- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/index.html